# Passing params in rails... Breakthrough in understanding params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, parameters

I have a simple has_many belongs_to relationship and I want to include the parent object for the view of the belongs_to model and I have had some success, but I want it to work better.

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :contest
end
class Contest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :submissions, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

In the case that works, I pass contest_id to submissions by placing it in the url:

```
   <%= link_to 'Submit Contest Entry', new_submission_path(:contest_id => @contest.id), 
                            :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-large mleft10' %>
```

So that, combined with a hidden_field:

```
 <%= f.hidden_field :contest_id %>
```

And a find_contest method in the controller (called with a before_filter):

```
def find_contest
  #the next line is giving the error (line 76)
  @contest = Contest.find(params[:submission][:contest_id])
end
```

Makes it work for submissions/new, but how do I add a find to the controller that just works across more than that one page, like if I want to access in show and index. Right now, I get an error:

```
Started GET "/submissions?contest_id=5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-01 16:01:45 -0800
Processing by SubmissionsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"contest_id"=>"5"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 ORDER BY users.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 37ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/submissions_controller.rb:76:in `find_contest'
```

[edited]
Adding show action for submissions:

```
before_filter :find_contest, :except => [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def find_contest
  @contest = Contest.find(params[:submission][:contest_id])
end

def show
  contest_id = @submission.contest_id
  @submission = @commentable = Submission.find(params[:id])
  @comments = @commentable.comments.order(:created_at).reverse
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html  # show.html.erb
    format.json  { render :json => @submission }
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, can you show the code in line 76, and all the respective method?

Comment: You have a `Parameters: {"contest_id"=>"5"}`, try replace: `Contest.find(params[:submission][:contest_id])` with `Contest.find(params[:contest_id])`

Comment: @KienThanh I get an error: Couldn't find Contest without an ID on that method. How does one normally pass a parent object's instance into the offsprings controller. I know you have to look it up through the key `contest_id` located in the submissions model, but I don't know what it looks like.

Comment: @pablo89 I edited the question by adding a comment in the third coded section to point out line 76.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer to this question, but I've used two lines for both index and show, which can probably be refactored to one(edit note: Pablo89 suggested a refactor for show, which is included, but index is still two lines)

The two lines are really important in both cases, however, especially to a beginner, and here's why:

To pass the parent_id (contest_id) into the associated view (show submission), I defined @submission (@associated) using submission_id from params (commentable is in there for another purpose and can be ignored).

```
@submission = @commentable = Submission.find(params[:id])
```

Params are found in the website address, in this case:

```
http://localhost:3000/submissions/41
```

41 is submission_id. That's obvious.

Rails uses the address of the page, found in the browser window to assign the instance values. I didn't know where Rails was finding params prior to this because Rails does so many things automatically. params is the web page address. DOH!

I then assigned contest_id using @submission's contest_id key, required as part of the belongs_to association, and use find to get to @contest

```
contest_id = @submission.contest_id
@contest = Contest.find(contest_id)
```

As Pablo89 points out, because of rails associative powers, there two lines can be reduced to one:

```
@contest = @submission.contest
```

In index, there is no @submission, so I pass the contest_id to this page through the link_to that page, found in two places contests/show and submissions/show:

```
<%= link_to 'Browse All Submissions', submissions_path(:contest_id => @contest.id), :class => 'btn btn-mini pull-right' %>
```

Clicking on the link takes you to submissions/index and results in this address:

```
http://localhost:3000/submissions?contest_id=4
```

(:contest_id => @contest.id) adds ?contest_id=4 to the address so I can access it from submissions controller via "params"

For beginners like me, this is an important way to build an understanding of params, because the address of the page is where Rails is assigning its instance variables from like @submission or @contest.

A nested route would look like this:

contests/5/submssions/41

If you are using nested routes, the contest and submission values are in the address, right there, waiting to be used! The address is also known as "params", (I repeat it to get though to other learners with thick skulls like me), but if you're not using nested routes, the parent id has to be passed another way, like by adding it to the link_to in the above example.

From there, to access the ?contest_id=4 I put the following in the index action of submissions:

```
contest_id = params[:contest_id]
@contest = Contest.find(contest_id)
```

This is a bit of a breakthrough for me because up to this point, I never knew what params was or how it worked, just that it worked.

By understanding this basic concept, that most experienced developers know so well they don't think to mention, I understand so much more about the controller.

I may or may not be correct in everything I've relayed here, but I hope this is helpful for other beginners. I now feel so much more confident in my ability to figure things out. Prior to this much of what I was doing with params was trying different ways until it worked without any basic understanding. It makes me laugh now, because it really is so simple. I think the word params is somewhat formidable, in that it could refer to any parameters anywhere.

Now I know, it's the web address parameters that Rails is using to assign those values. Wow! What a breakthrough...

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing to the action **index** of the controller **SubmissionsController**; I assume that inside of the action **index** you are calling the method **find_contest**. The error is because inside of the method **find_contest** you are trying to get the value of **params[:submission][:contest_id]**, but such param doesn't exists; the param that you are getting is **params[:contest_id]**.

What you can do in order to manage the same method trough many actions is change the method and pass a parameter, like this:

```
def find_contest(contest_id)
  @contest = Contest.find(contest_id)
end

def index
  find_contest(params[:contest_id])
  #some other code...
end
```

But, if you are using something like a **before_filter**, you can check inside of **find_contest** method if **params[:contest_id].nil?** and if isn't nil use it, otherwise use **params[:submission][:contest_id]**.

Comment: Getting this error: 'Started GET "/submissions/41" 
Processing by SubmissionsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"41"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 ORDER BY users.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
  Submission Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "submissions".* FROM "submissions" WHERE "submissions"."id" = $1 ORDER BY submissions.created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", "41"]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 88ms

**ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)):**
  app/controllers/submissions_controller.rb:79:in `find_contest2'`

Comment: If I put this in #show `contest_id = @submission.contest_id`, I get a response of **/submissions/41** on this: `<%= link_to @contest, @contest %>`

Comment: I've just watched your code, I get lost because `contest_id = @submission.contest_id` but there is no initialization of `@submission` until later. Also, the method `find_contest2` is like the method that I suggested you? (And I didn't see you using the object `@contest`, also I didn't see any `before_filter` related to `find_contest2`). Finally, what is the response that you get in `contest_id = @submission.contest_id` (like you said 3 comments ago)?

Comment: Okay, I got it working, but if you can re-factor it in an answer, I can accept, given the fact that you have helped me arrive at an answer, one which I know can be improved: 
`contest_id = @submission.contest_id \n
 @contest = Contest.find(contest_id)`

Comment: If `submission` and `contest` are associated, you can do something like `@contest = @submission.contest`

Comment: that works for show, but see my explanation for index in the answer. I hope you can also come up with a simplified way to do that and post both as an answer.